# Cannot access form.first_name and form.email from django default authentication form

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication, custom-fields

I am using the default Django AuthenticationForm() for the user login feature. Now when I see inside the user model in Django admin it has fields like username, email address, first name last name and active status.

But in my sign-in.html page I can only access form.username and form.password, but cant access to form.email and form.first_name??

My views:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            authlog(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid username or password')
            # back_page = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
            return redirect('login')
            # messages.error(request, student_form.errors, 'Incorrect')
            # return HttpResponse(back_page)
    else:
        content = {
            'form': AuthenticationForm()
        }
        return render(request, 'sign-in.html', content)

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><span class="fas fa-envelope"></span></span>

     {{form.emailaddress}}
</div>


<div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2"><span class="fas fa-unlock-alt"></span></span>
      {{form.password}}
</div>
```

Here I can access form.password and form.username but cant login with email address. But we know we should be able to login with email address as well.

I have the picture here of the html page.

[Sign-In Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZobc.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Authentication form only have the fields username and password. So you cannot access any other field since they aren't defined.

If you want other fields on the authentication form you can change the **USERNAME_FIELD** in your settings as stated [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms).

You can also write a brand new authentication form if you really need something more complicated.